# Appending select object and text inside a div using JQuery

Tags: jquery, html-select

```js
 
 $("#subBtn").click(function(){
   var ifType = $("#pcker").clone();
   $("#scontainer").append("<div class='row'><div class='col'>"+ifType+"</div></div>");

});
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col">

<select class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true" id="pcker">
<option value='gag'>raps</option>
<option value='gag'>Experiments</option>
<option value='gag'>value</option>
<option value='gag'>select</option>
<option value='gag'>bootstrap</option>
</option>

</select>


<button class="btn" type="button" id="subBtn" value="test">Add Button</button>
</div>
<div class="row" id="scontainer"></div>
</div>
 </body>



</html>
```

I am cloning an HTML Select Option using JQuery

```
var ifType = $("#thevalue\\.type").clone();
```

where **thevalue.type** is the id of the select.

There are several selects that I cloned. I want to print them on a single line by appending them to one div container. I tried using the following for one select:

```
$("#scontainer").append("<div class='row'>");
$("#scontainer").append("<div class='col'>");
$("#scontainer").append(ifType);
$("#scontainer").append("</div>");
$("#scontainer").append("</div>");
```

However this generates an HTML of the form

`<div class='row'></div><div class='col'></div> **ifType value here**.`

How do I do it so that the cloned select object is inside the row and col divs?

Answer (score 1):

Use next:

```
$("#scontainer").append("<div class='row'><div class='col'>"+ifType+"</div></div>");
```

instead of

```
$("#scontainer").append("<div class='row'>");
$("#scontainer").append("<div class='col'>");
$("#scontainer").append(ifType);
$("#scontainer").append("</div>");
$("#scontainer").append("</div>");
```

According to your snippet:

```js
$("#subBtn").click(function(){
    $("#pcker").clone().appendTo('#scontainer');
});
```

```html
 
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col">

<select class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true" id="pcker">
<option value='gag'>raps</option>
<option value='gag'>Experiments</option>
<option value='gag'>value</option>
<option value='gag'>select</option>
<option value='gag'>bootstrap</option>

</select>

</div>
</div>

<button class="btn" type="button" id="subBtn" value="test">Add Button</button>

<div class='row'><div class='col' id="scontainer"> 

</div></div>
 
 </body>
</html>
```

```js
$("#subBtn").click(function(){
     var ifType = $("#pcker").clone(true);
     $("#scontainer").append(ifType);
});
```

```html
 <html>
 <head>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
 <div class="row">
 <div class="col">

 <select class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true" id="pcker">
        <option value='gag'>raps</option>
        <option value='gag'>Experiments</option>
        <option value='gag'>value</option>
        <option value='gag'>select</option>
        <option value='gag'>bootstrap</option>
 </select>

 </div>
 </div>

 <button class="btn" type="button" id="subBtn" value="test">Add Button</button>

 <div class='row'><div class='col' id="scontainer"> 

 </div></div>
         
 </body>
 </html>
```

also I suggest you `append` it to the `body` and don't use `id` attributes, cause `id` will be duplicated and non-unique.

Comment: I've tried this and it doesn't work. I've added a snippet of the problem.

Comment: @MontySwanson, I've updated my answer. Now it works according to your request

Comment: Thanks. This solves the problem of my snippet but not the actual code I posted. I posted a new question and updated the code to match my actual requirement.

Answer (score 1):

I just changed you code a little and think it is working append selects on the same row

the html

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col">

        <select class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true" id="pcker">
      <option value='gag'>raps</option>
      <option value='gag'>Experiments</option>
      <option value='gag'>value</option>
      <option value='gag'>select</option>
      <option value='gag'>bootstrap</option>
      </option>

    </select>
        <button class="btn" type="button" id="subBtn" value="test">Add Button</button>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div id="scontainer" class='col'>

    </div>
</div>
```

js

```
  $("#subBtn").click(function() {
    var ifType = $("#pcker").clone();
    $("#scontainer").append(
       ifType 
    );
  });
```

Comment: This will still render the cloned selects outside the row and col divs in the original question.

Comment: if you want all selects in the same row you could try this as html ```<div class="row">
 <div id="scontainer" class="col">

  <select class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true" id="pcker">
      <option value='gag'>raps</option>
      <option value='gag'>Experiments</option>
      <option value='gag'>value</option>
      <option value='gag'>select</option>
      <option value='gag'>bootstrap</option>
      </option>

    </select>
 </div>
</div>
  <button class="btn" type="button" id="subBtn" value="test">Add Button</button>```